# How to make a transparent proxy on macOS with Docker instead of Virtualbox?

Tags: docker, docker-machine, transparentproxy, tun-tap

There is a github project [VRouter](https://github.com/icymind/VRouter) which make Openwrt image as an vbox on macOS and routing the traffic to the NIC of the virtual machine as a transparent proxy. I would like to know that is it possible to do these things o with docker?
As fas as I know, docker for mac actually run inside a virtual machine on mac and there is no docker0 NIC on macOS. I found a project [tuntaposx](http://tuntaposx.sourceforge.net/) and a tuntap support shim installer for Docker for Mac [docker-tuntap-osx](https://github.com/AlmirKadric-Published/docker-tuntap-osx) which make it access docker container inside the virtual machine from macOS instead of publish ports possible. But What's the next step? I am quite confused about network issue. Can someone  give me a hint about it?

Answer (score 0):

Docker requires a Linux host to run. It's unlikely it will ever directly support MacOS, or Windows, without some kind of VM running.

Docker isn't a virtual machine. It uses various features of the Linux kernel to essentially simulate a virtual server, but it isn't actually doing full virtualization.

Comment: When using a virtual machine on macOS, we can route to it. And when using docker on linux host, we can route to docker. So is it possible to combine those two steps on macOS?